# How to count the number of times a value recurs in a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

If you have a recursive function (e.g. the Fibonacci sequence):

```
def fib(n):
    """Return Fibonacci of n; assumes n is an int >= 0."""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

How would one count, for example, the number of times fib(2) occurs when fib(20) is called?

Comment: you could implement a counter  taht you pass as a variable in your function, or modify a global variable each time...

Comment: it seems i misread your question...i read recurs as recurses...sorry

Comment: You want to count the number of calls to `fib(i)` for each `i` when computing `fib(n)`, correct?

Comment: `global num_of_twos; if n == 2: num_of_twos+=1`

Comment: @Natecat exactly... If you want to do it on the fly instead I guess you'd add a second parameter to the "fib" function ?

Comment: skeletonsaurus: Are you going to clarify your question or select one of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a decorator:

```
import functools

def count(f):
    """Count function calls."""
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def counted(*args, **kwargs):
        counted.count_calls += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    counted.count_calls = 0
    return counted

fib = count(fib)
fib(5)
fib.count_calls
# 15
```

Alternatively, you can now prepend any function definition using this decorator and the `@` symbol:

```
@count
def fib(n):
    ...

fib(5)
fib.count_calls
# 15
```

Note, this decorator accumulates function calls:

```
fib(5)
fib(5)
fib.count_calls
# 30
```

This is a clever implementation that takes advantage of lesser known [function attributes](http://adambeagle.com/blog/python-function-attributes-i/).  Note, the original decorator is modified from John DiNero's `count` function discussed in his [lecture on Memoization](https://youtu.be/DWhsOSHjY98?t=2m16s) where he addresses this specific issue.

Comment: While I agree the implementation is clever, it should be noted that it has a side-effect of—at least—doubling the function-call overhead of the original.

Comment: Thank you @martineau for the comment.  To clarify, you are saying each call to `fib` also makes an overall call to `count`, which adds to the total calls to the stack, not to `count_calls`?

Comment: Not exactly. I meant that the decorated version of the function calls the original which calls the decorated which calls the original, etc—which is double the number of function calls there were when the original just called itself. Using a global variable or passing an extra argument would probably be faster than that.

Comment: @martineau yes, that is what I interpreted and a good point with regards to performance.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to count all invocations of `fib`. The dictionary has to be cleared before the first call to `fib`.

```
calls = defaultdict(int)
```

In the function, update the corresponding entry in the dictionary before doing anything else:

```
def fib(n):
  global calls
  """Assumes n an int >= 0
     Returns Fibonacci of n"""
  calls[n] += 1
  if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: Unless it has been changed, that isn't how you use `defaultdict`. It should be `calls = defaultdict(int)`. Also might wanna mention that you have to `from collections import defaultdict`

Comment: @Natecat Same difference: 0 is an instance of `int()`.

Comment: Except 0 isn't callable, while the function int is.

Comment: You could also use `Counter`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def fib(n, counts_dict):
    counts_dict[n] += 1
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1, counts_dict) + fib(n-2), counts_dict
```

Where `counts_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)`

Comment: @Natecat seems like a good idea, but then the caller won't have a reference to it and won't be able to access the counts.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i tried ... thinks like work fine

```
def fib(n):
    global counter
    if (n == 0 or n == 1):
        counter=counter+1
        return 1
    else:
        counter=counter+1
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
def countfib(n):
    global counter
    counter = 0
    fib(5);
    global count
    count=counter
    counter = 0
    return count
counter=0
count=0
print fib(5)
count=countfib(5)
print count
```

Output:

> 8 
>   15

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly what the recurring values you want to count are, so I'm guessing it's the number of times the (recursive) function was called with the same argument (or group of them, if there's more than one).

In the code below, a decorator named `tally_recurring_args()` is used to wrap the function in some code to do this. To simplify things and avoid reinventing the wheel, a `collections.Counter` is used to tally the number of calls of every unique combination of arguments to the function. This is made a attribute of the function so it can be easily referenced in the `wrapper` every call to the decorated function.

```
import collections
import functools

def tally_recurring_args(func):
    func._args_counter = collections.Counter()  @ add attribute to func

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        key = ', '.join(str(arg) for arg in args)
        func._args_counter[key] += 1
        return func(*args)

    return wrapper

@tally_recurring_args
def fib(n):
    """Return Fibonacci of n; assumes n is an int >= 0."""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print('fib(5) -> {}'.format(fib(5)))
for args, count in sorted(fib._args_counter.items()):
    print('fib({}): called {} time{}'.format(args, count,
                                             's' if count > 1 else ''))
```

Output:

```
fib(5) -> 8
fib(0): called 3 times
fib(1): called 5 times
fib(2): called 3 times
fib(3): called 2 times
fib(4): called 1 time
fib(5): called 1 time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib(n, x):
    c = 1 if n == x else 0

    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1, c
    else:
        fA, cA = fib(n - 1, x)
        fB, cB = fib(n - 2, x)
        return fA + fB, cA + cB + c
```

If I've not messed up the logic, this function accepts `n` and `x` and returns a tuple `(y, c)` s.t. `fib(n, _)=y` and `fib(x, _)` was invoked `c` times during the calculation.

This is a purer alternative to the other proposed solutions that involve updating a dictionary. It rests on the assumption that OP only requires the number of times `f(k, _)` was invoked for one specific `k`, and so avoids filling a dictionary from which only one value is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without global variables:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def fib(n, count=None):
    if count is None:
        count = defaultdict(int)
    count[n] += 1
    if n in (0, 1):
        return 1, count
    return fib(n - 1)[0] + fib(n - 2)[0], count
```

The `fib` function now returns a tuple: the first element is the desired value and the second element is a dictionary containing the information of how many times each value the `fib` function was called on.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an function attribute. Just like a static variable.

```
def fib(n): 
    """Return Fibonacci of n; assumes n is an int >= 0."""
    If hasattr(fib, 'cnt'):
        fib.cnt += 1
    else:
        fib.cnt = 1
    if n == 0 or n == 1: 
        return 1 
    else: 
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

fib.cnt =0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using global:

```
c = 0
def fib(n):
    global c
    c += 1
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution without global variable, but done through value passing:

```
def fibo(n, c):
if n <= 2 and n > 0:
    return n-1, c
else:
    n1, c1 = fibo(n-1,c+1)
    n2, c2 = fibo(n-2,1)
    return n1+n2, c1+c2
```